# Links in Marketing SMS displaying as plain text

Tags: ios, ios11

We're sending marketing SMS that have a URL in them, it's formatted like this:

https://hostname/route?token=VBQTkrri7cBPm_EQ_flpnw&source_channel=sms&utm_source=sms

The link works on Android and ios pre 11. But on 11 it displays as text. Is there something wrong with the URL?

Also, we were using bit.ly but our client can't afford to upgrade their account so for the last week of every month they send long urls once they exceed their limit for whatever plan they're on.

Answer (score 0):

We were including offer value details, with a dollar sign. And apparently the dollar sign confuses some new feature where you can text people money. Removing the dollar sign fixes it.